# double comparison. explanation of different results

Tags: java

I try to train for scjp.

I have this code:

```
 System.out.println(0.8==0.1+0.1+0.1+0.1+0.1+0.1+0.1+0.1);//false
 System.out.println(0.8==((0.1+0.1)+(0.1+0.1))+((0.1+0.1)+(0.1+0.1))); // true
```

output:

```
true
false
```

I know that right comparison something like this:

```
abs(a1-a2)<epsilon
```

But this results is strange for me. Who can explain their for me?

Are valid similar questions for scjp?

Answer (score 1):

In Java, double values are IEEE floating point numbers. Unless they are a power of 2 (or sums of powers of 2, e.g. 1/8 + 1/4 = 3/8), they cannot be represented exactly, even if they have high precision. Some floating point operations will compound the round-off error present in these floating point numbers. In cases you've described above :
The sum of 0.1+0.1....8 times result 0.7999999999999999 whereas in second sum is result 0.8 thts y it result true.

Comment: How do you think, Is it really to predict without program execution?

Comment: @gstackoverflow its not possible without execution to predict the result.